# Добавить ноовый столбец в существующую таблицу peewee

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, peewee

Есть таблица с данными, нужно добавить новый столбец, но если это сделать в коде то получаю ошибку `peewee.OperationalError: no such column: x.xx`, как это сделать в БД `sqlite3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если просто, то через sqlite добавьть вручную таблице столбец, чтобы имя столбца и тип совпадал с полем модели в коде:

```
ALTER TABLE x ADD xx INTEGER;
```

---

Если сложнее (и правильнее), то сделайте скрипт [миграции](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#schema-migrations).

Например, сделайте папку `migrations`, в ней создайте файл, пусть будет `001.py`:

```
from playhouse.migrate import *

DB_NAME = 'db.sqlite'

my_db = SqliteDatabase(DB_NAME)
migrator = SqliteMigrator(my_db)

with my_db.atomic():
    migrate(
        migrator.add_column('x', 'xx', IntegerField(null=True)),
    )
```

Выполните файл и тогда база будет актуализирована с кодом.